# can't run or deploy Google App Engine from IntelliJ

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-intellij

I'd like to deploy an app on GAE, but I think I must be missing something.

- I've downloaded the google cloud code plugin for IntelliJ.
- I've installed the gcloud SDK
- I've authenticated with my google account

I've created a new project of type GAE project, which in the project structure window shows the GAE facet, and has an appengine-web.xml file.

Yet when I try and run my new project the log shows an error:

`21:51  Error running 'Google App Engine Deployment': Deployment is not selected`

I presume it's referring to this window:

[image]

As you can see there are no deployments.  When I try to edit the Run configuration, there's not much there:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you try adding AppEngine support explicitly, i.e. using Tools -> Cloud Code -> App Engine -> Add App Engine Support -> App Engine Standard menu? Will the deployment target appear or anything changes?

Comment: To follow up on this. Are you using community edition? If so you need to have a Maven project since exploded wars are not supported. If you are on Ultimate Edition, please check Project Structure -> Artifacts to ensure that you have an App Engine Standard artifact. If you don't, @Ivan's suggestion here can help you bootstrap this.

Comment: If I attempt to add AppEngine support explicitly, I get an error message saying "All modules already have AppEngine support"

Comment: I have switched the project to maven, which created a pom.xml, but the problem is still there